# Cacheput annotation not updating cache Hazelcast cache

Tags: java, caching, spring-boot, hazelcast

I am developing a java application in Spring Boot. I am using Hazelcast for caching, but it does not updates the cache when a method is annotated with @CachePut
My Code goes something like this :

```
@CachePut(cacheNames = "cachetest")
public void addData(com.nikesh.webapp.model.CacheTest cacheObj) {
    repo.save(cacheObj);
}

@Cacheable(cacheNames = "cachetest")
public List<com.nikesh.webapp.model.CacheTest> getCacheTestData() {
    return repo.findAll();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "cachetest")
public List<com.nikesh.webapp.model.CacheTest> getCacheTestDataByPhone(
        String phone) {
    Query q = manager.createNamedQuery("byPhone");
    q.setParameter("phone", phone);
    return q.getResultList();
}

@CacheEvict(cacheNames = "cachetest")
public boolean clearCache() {
    return true;
}
```

CacheEvict is working properly. Am i missing anything?

Comment: Spring Boot is supposed to intercept the calls and forward them to Hazelcast. In case the annotation does not work, I'd expect a Spring Boot issue. Unfortunately I'm not a Spring Boot expert.

Comment: The method annotated with `@CachePut` is _void_

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify cache key in annotations.

Can you try like following:

```
@CachePut(cacheNames = "cachetest", key="#p0.phone")
public CacheTest addData(com.nikesh.webapp.model.CacheTest cacheObj) {
    return repo.save(cacheObj);
}

@Cacheable(cacheNames = "cachetest", key="'phone'")
public List<com.nikesh.webapp.model.CacheTest> getCacheTestData() {
    return repo.findAll();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "cachetest", key="#p0")
public List<com.nikesh.webapp.model.CacheTest> getCacheTestDataByPhone(
        String phone) {
    Query q = manager.createNamedQuery("byPhone");
    q.setParameter("phone", phone);
    return q.getResultList();
}

@CacheEvict(cacheNames = "cachetest")
public boolean clearCache() {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I am not so sure how to work with keys. I will try like this but can you give me any link which explains how to work with keys in cache?

Comment: this is a nice tutorial i found for you -> http://websystique.com/spring/spring-4-cacheable-cacheput-cacheevict-caching-cacheconfig-enablecaching-tutorial/

Comment: Its not working when i call getCacheTestData method. First time when i call it fetches from database, then i added one more record (addData method), then if i call  getCacheTestData i am not getting newly added record. I get it only after i do CacheEvict

Comment: I added key attribute to Cacheable on getCacheTestData, can you try like that? i think spring put all list with a single generated key, so lets see how it works after specifying key field.

Comment: No its not working, now data does not get updated even after CacheEvict.

Comment: Neil suggested above that your method addData returns void. So it does not put any object to cache. So you should return what repo.save(cacheObj) returns. See my edits